# Can you specify the language to use with ml-kit an android when detecting text?

Tags: android, ocr, google-mlkit

Is it possible to somehow limit the languages used by ml-kit on android?

I have it detecting text from an image, however some of the words it's detecting as another language when in fact they are all in English.

I haven't found any options when setting up the 'TextRecognizer' object to specify the language (aside from limiting it to just latin script), is there a way to set the language to detect?

Thanks

Comment: i don't see any way to do this unless you aren't using Some Specific languages which has separate Supports in V2 like Korean .. [This code lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/mlkit-android-translate#0) suggests using detection API .. i m not sure if its the only way to go ..

Comment: Note according the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/identification) you should get confidence levels for languages detected.

Comment: ML Kit does not current support this capability, but will consider this when planning for future feature enhancements.